# How to use Border.BackgroundSizing/Border.BackgroundTransition properties in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm working on a lab to get some animation working on my button objects.  I want to be able to change a border background size at a specified rate of transition so that it transitions smoothly upon pointer entery into the object's 'HitTest' area.  I've tried 'Duration' but to no avail.

Here's what I have thus far:

In my Xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="mg" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Button x:Name="g" Width="200" Height="30" Content="Click for Flyout" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Coral">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                
                <Grid Width="300" Height="150" CornerRadius="7" Background="Beige" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Spacing="1">
                        
                        <Border x:Name="b1" Width="150" Height="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border.BackgroundTransition>
                                <BrushTransition />
                            </Border.BackgroundTransition>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="r1" Width="100" Height="30" Fill="DarkGoldenrod" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PointerEntered="{x:Bind Entered}" PointerExited="{x:Bind Exited}"></Rectangle>
                        </Border>

                        <Border x:Name="b2" Width="150" Height="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border.BackgroundTransition>
                                <BrushTransition />
                            </Border.BackgroundTransition>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="r2" Width="100" Height="30" Fill="PaleVioletRed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PointerEntered="{x:Bind Entered}" PointerExited="{x:Bind Exited}"></Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    
</Grid>
```

In the code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow
{
    public Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush Background { get; set; }
    public BackgroundSizing BackgroundSizing { get; set; }
    public BrushTransition BackgroundTransition { get; set; }
    public System.TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    public void Entered(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle _r = sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
        BackgroundSizing bs = new BackgroundSizing();
        BrushTransition bt = new BrushTransition();
        
        if (_r == r1)
        {
            r1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
            r1.StrokeThickness = 2;
            
            b1.BackgroundSizing = bs;
            b1.BackgroundTransition = bt;
            
            b1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        }
        else if (_r == r2)
        {
            r2.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
            r2.StrokeThickness = 2;

            b2.BackgroundSizing = bs;
            b2.BackgroundTransition = bt;
            
            b2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        }
        else { return; }
    }

    public void Exited(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle _r = sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
        if (_r == r1)
        {
            b1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            r1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            r1.StrokeThickness = .5;
        }
        else if ( _r == r2)
        {
            b2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            r2.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            r2.StrokeThickness = .5;
        }
        else { return; }
    }
}
```

I got a bit of the effect I wanted from it, but I would like more control over the duration setting.  I just haven't found enough information on this to be able to get it done.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `UserControl` and `VisualStates`:

**CustomRectangle.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI;

namespace Example;

public sealed partial class CustomRectangle : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Stroke),
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(CustomRectangle),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(StrokeThickness),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(CustomRectangle),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerOverBackgroundColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(PointerOverBackgroundColor),
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(CustomRectangle),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomRectangle()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.PointerEntered += (s, e) =>
        {
            // "succeeded" should return "true".
            bool succeeded = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PointerOver", true);
        };
        this.PointerExited += (s, e) =>
        {
            bool succeeded = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
        };
    }

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
    }

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    public Color PointerOverBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(PointerOverBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(PointerOverBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**CustomRectangle.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<UserControl
    x:Class="Example.CustomRectangle"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:Example"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle
            x:Name="Rectangle"
            MinHeight="24"
            Fill="{x:Bind Background, Mode=OneWay}"
            Stroke="{x:Bind Stroke, Mode=OneWay}"
            StrokeThickness="{x:Bind StrokeThickness, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                            To="5"
                            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            To="{x:Bind PointerOverBackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

and you can use it like this:

```xml
<Button Content="Flyout">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Grid
                Width="300"
                ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
                ColumnSpacing="10">
                <local:CustomRectangle
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Background="SkyBlue"
                    PointerOverBackgroundColor="Blue"
                    Stroke="Yellow" />
                <local:CustomRectangle
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Background="HotPink"
                    PointerOverBackgroundColor="Red"
                    Stroke="Green" />
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: Andrew KeepCoding,  thanks for the info!  I got alot of good tips out of it: how to create a custom element in Xaml, how to create a custom control to apply to the custom element of type rectangle, and how to associate a 'UserControl' markup assembly to a custom element for control of animated properties... not to mention the dependency property code structure which really helps clear things up!  Whew!  I'll try this out, it'll take me some time though.  I'll post my results later.  Thanks again!

Comment: Andrew, I created a new project, got all the markup/code typed in exactly as you posted aside from 'PointerOverBackgroundColor' which was changed to 'EnteredBackgroundColor', and colors such as blue, yellow, red, and green were changed to preferred colors.  Everything looks good, everything is in order -- no errors or squiggly lines -- but no effect takes place when the pointer traverses over the rectangles.  I'm not sure if it is an issue with WinUI3 and the duration property.  Any ideas?

Comment: `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` should return `true`. What does it return?

Comment: I have it coded the as suggested: VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PointerOver", true); --

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific. Is `succeeded` `true` when you debug it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  How can I debug it to check for it?

Comment: You can place a [breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022) at the very line `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` is called and see if `succeeded` is `true` or `false`.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I changed the 'PointerOver' names to 'Entered' names so I went ahead and changed 'VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, **"PointerOver"**, true); to 'VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, **"Entered"**, true); just now... It seems to have gone a bit further now; it's giving me the following error now: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object.'

Comment: You might get this exception message if the element named "Rectangle" doesn't have a `Fill` property, for example when it's not a `Rectangle` element. Are you sure you don't have any misspellings around this? The code above is based on a working sample app I implemented for this answer. It should work.

Comment: The markup is ok as a <Rectangle /> element;  I changed the name you suggested "Rectangle" to "r" for clarification, but I still get the same error:   Cannot resolve TargetProperty (r.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object.' -- the focus of the exception is located at the 'this.VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Entered", true);' line of code within the CustomRectangle.xaml.cs file...

Comment: Can you add the oode of the `UserControl` (C# and XAML) in your question?

Comment: @jv1597, have you made it work? Also see [Easing functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/key-frame-and-easing-function-animations#easing-functions) for more control.

Comment: I posted an answer to get some code illustrated... it posted above Andrew's post on the message board.

Comment: The code you posted has several issues. That is not the way you should create/use `UserControl`s. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4). I also have WinUI 3 videos, including [this](https://youtu.be/AisI7MCVrC8?si=Dfp5eIBa-gV1VY1H), which is related to `UserControl`s. I hope it helps.

Comment: Andrew, that doc link really helped clear things up... I found some examples of some simple logic that might help at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs?view=winrt-22621.

Comment: It would make things a lot easier if I could get the pointer entered methods done simplistically as with any typical Button function within the MainWindow class, and have it load an instance of VisualStateManager and the GoToState method to run the storyboard animations upon pointer entry; all done from C#.

Comment: The code in my answer is the easiest way to do the animations you requested. And as I said, it should work since I actually created a test project for this answer. Please give it a try without changing the names, except the namespaces.

Comment: Andrew, I tried the code exactly as you posted with changes to the current namespace to match up with the project name, and it worked excellently!  :)  It looks great for what I needed to do.  I'll be fiddling with it to get the effect to extend outwardly instead though to give the buttons a focused effect.  Thanks for the info!  I'll go ahead and put a check mark on this one.